# Eclipse format upon open

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

Eclipse can automatically format a file upon save.  One use for this is to insure everyone's code meets a common corporate standard.  Let's say "hypothetically" this standard is dumb.  Is it possible to have a second set of formatting rules that get automatically applied on file open, so you can work sanely?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you cannot specify one set of formatting rules when opening a file, and another set of formatting rules when saving a file because Eclipse does not provide the functionality to reformat a file using different formatting rules on open. But even if that were true, you would still have problems:

- You open your file and Eclipse automatically uses your "good" formatter.
- You work on the file and save it because you are going to lunch (or Eclipse autosaves while you are on the phone), and the "dumb" formatter is automatically used.
- You would now have to close the file and reopen it to resume using the "good" formatter.

However, an alternative approach that would achieve what you want with very little effort is:

- Create your own profile with your "good" formatting rules (e.g. For Java use **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> New...**).
- Make that the active profile for the project you are working on (e.g. For Java use **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Configure Project Specific Settings...**).
- Make your changes and test locally using the "good" formatter, but immediately prior to committing any changes to source control switch to using the "dumb" formatting rules.

Of course that approach is potentially disastrous if you fail to revert a modified file to use the "dumb" formatter; a one line change in the source could result in thousands of differences within source control due to reformatting.

Perhaps I'm being unfair, but your question sets off flashing red warning lights in my head. Is it simply that you don't like the formatting rules that have been laid down? If not, what would be a scenario where the hypothetical approach you describe would make good sense?

Comment: A friend showed me a truly appalling file from a company I won't name, (imagine Java written by a Fortran person), so this thought occurred to me.

Comment: @JohnHascall OK, gotcha. So I guess your use case is that you want to be able to safely reformat a file for readability without necessarily changing it?

Comment: Yes to be able to always reformat to one standard on the way in and to always reformat the output (not the edit window) when saving.  But seems not possible.

Comment: I want this too. It would be the ultimate answer to those "code-nazis" and their so-called "best practices" (absolutely the best? Can't get any better? Best according to whom?). It would work like this:

Loading a file formats it in the programmer's preferred style.
Saving a file formats it in the standard style but does not change it in the editor!

Easy peasy. Everyone's happy.

Comment: @RextheStrange That's an interesting idea, since it addresses the concern that thousands of differences between two versions in your source control system could arise inadvertently from a simple one line change. But even if you are certain that your preferences and layout conventions are superior to those followed by everyone else (a dubious claim), it can only lead to trouble in the long run. I guess you could write a plugin to do what you suggest though.